# LSTM/GRU TImeSeries multioutput strategy forecasts give dropped values

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Currently, I'm playing with Stocks Predictions task which I try to solve using LSTM/GRU.

**Problem: After training LSTM/GRU I get huge drop predicted values**
[image]

**Model training process**
[image]

**Train, test** data is simply generated using `pd.shift` in series_to_supervised function. 
[image]

```
df['Mid'] = df['Low'] + df['High'] / 2

n_lag = 1 # Lag columns back
n_seq = 1*50 # TimeSteps to predict
seq_col = 'Mid'
seq_col_t = f'{seq_col}(t)'
split_date = '2018-01-01'


def series_to_supervised(data: pd.DataFrame, 
                         seq_col: str, 
                         n_in: int = 1, 
                         n_out: int = 1, 
                         drop_seq_col: bool = True, 
                         dropna: bool = True):
    """Convert time series into supervised learning problem 
        {input sequence, forecast sequence}
    """
    # input sequence (t-n, ... t-1) -> pisitive shift
    for i in range(n_in, 0, -1):
        data[f'{seq_col}(t-{i})'] = data[seq_col].shift(i)
    # no sequence -> no shift
    data[f'{seq_col}(t)'] = data[seq_col]
    for i in range(1, n_out+1):
        # forecast sequence (t, t+1, ... t+n) -> negative shift
        data[f'{seq_col}(t+{i})'] = data[seq_col].shift(-i)
    if drop_seq_col:
        data = data.drop(seq_col, axis=1)
    if dropna:
        data.dropna(inplace=True) 
    return data

df = series_to_supervised(df, seq_col=seq_col, n_in=n_lag, n_out=n_seq)

mask = df.index < split_date
train, test = df[mask], df[~mask]

X_cols = ['Mid(t-1)']
y_cols = train.filter(like='Mid(t+').columns

X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = train[X_cols], train[y_cols], test[X_cols], test[y_cols]

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))

# also returns np.ndarray
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.fit_transform(X_test)
y_train = y_train.values
y_test = y_test.values

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM, GRU
from keras.optimizers import Adam, RMSprop, Adamax
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

def get_model(X, y, n_batch):
    num_classes=y.shape[1]
    # design network
    model = Sequential()
    # For Stock Predictions has to be used LSTM stateful=True
    model.add(GRU(10, batch_input_shape=(n_batch, X.shape[1], X.shape[2]), stateful=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes))
    opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
    # opt = RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001)
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=opt)
    return model

def reshape_batch(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, n_batch):
    # reshape training into [samples, timesteps, features]
    X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1])
    X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1, X_test.shape[1])

    # cut to equally divided n_batches (without reminder). 
    # needed for LSTM stateful=True
    train_cut = X_train.shape[0] % n_batch
    test_cut = X_test.shape[0] % n_batch

    if train_cut > 0:
        X_train = X_train[:-train_cut]
        y_train = y_train[:-train_cut]

    if test_cut > 0:
        X_test = X_test[:-test_cut]
        y_test = y_test[:-test_cut]

    return X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test

# fit an LSTM network to training data
def fit_lstm(X_train: np.ndarray, 
             y_train: np.ndarray, 
             n_lag: int,
             n_seq: int, 
             n_batch: int, 
             nb_epoch: int, 
             X_test: np.ndarray=None, 
             y_test: np.ndarray=None):

    model = get_model(X_train, y_train, n_batch)
    # fit network    
    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), callbacks=None,
                        epochs=nb_epoch, batch_size=n_batch, verbose=1, shuffle=False)
    print('Predict:', model.predict(X_test, batch_size=n_batch))
    model.reset_states()
    return model, history

n_batch = 32
nb_epoch = 40

X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = reshape_batch(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, n_batch)
model, history = fit_lstm(X_train, y_train, n_lag, n_seq, n_batch, nb_epoch, X_test=X_test, y_test=y_test)
```

**What I Have tried**

1. Different optimizers (kinda all available in keras)
2. DIfferent recurrent network structures (GRU/LSTM)
3. Different learning rates
4. Different epochs from 1 to 1500
5. Adding/Removing Drop layers with different params (0.1-0.7)
6. Different LSTM/GRU amount of neurons (1-100)
7. Number of LSTM/GRU layers, via return_sequences params with more Drop layers.
8. Different number of forecasts(t+1,t+2 ... t+n) features from 1-365
9. Different number of lag (t-1, t-2, t-n ...) features from 1-5
10. Different scale normalization borders (0,1) and (-1,1)
11. Different n_batch values: 1,8,16,32

    What can affect LSTM/GRU give so strange behaviour? And What else should I try to make it work the normal way?

Comment: the 'features' (last dimesion) of X_train are the lags of your series shifted... did I understand correctly?

Comment: @Marco Cerliani Hello;). Current Mid prices are (t). Features - are gotten using "negative shift" that gives us (t+n). Lags - are contrary gotten using "positive shift" that gives us (t-n). You can easely look at here to deliberately understand all the stuff. https://machinelearningmastery.com/convert-time-series-supervised-learning-problem-python/

Comment: ok, you are concatenating shift variable on the last dimension... this is not a common scenario for rnn. I suggest you this https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-time-series-forecasting/

Comment: @Marco Cerliani, Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try after work it out and give you the response